# How to run Flask app by flask run with blueprint template

Tags: python, flask

In a Python authorization app, in my main py I have the following code:

```
# main.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user

theapp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@theapp.route('/')

def index():
return render_template('index.html')
```

When I try:

```
FLASK_APP=main.py
FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a Blueprint is a way for you to organize your flask application into smaller and reusable applications. I am not sure why you have used it here in the `main.py`. 
 You could do that some other file, for example, you have a set of endpoints to implement login functionality in a separate file then what you should be doing is:

Assume you have a `login.py` .Sample Code looks like follows:

```py
from flask import Blueprint
bp = Blueprint('login_bp', __name__)

def login_bp():
    return bp
```

And the following code goes into you `main.py` , you need to start the Flask Server using `.run()`

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from login import login_bp  #Assume you have a module login and  I am importing login_bp from login.py 

theapp = Flask(__name__) #Creating Flask instance
theapp.register_blueprint(login_bp()) # Registering Blueprint here 

@theapp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


theapp.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=2019, debug=True) #Starting the Flask Server
```

Hope this works, please do look out for documents and code example to get deeper insights.

Comment: I am a Junior Python developer but I know how it works. If you go to this page: https://scotch.io/tutorials/authentication-and-authorization-with-flask-login#toc-install-packages you will see that the authour is running the app without setting the flask run etc, so he is not making any instances of the Flask.

Comment: Please check out in his ```__init__.py``` he does create a flask instance in the ```create_app()``` function. Regarding starting the server, you can either use the Flask CLI or the pythonic ```.run()```, depends on your choice.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a gist or you want me to explain any part of this answer?  You want me to build a sample app?